# How to replace repeated matches?

Tags: python, regex

I'd like to remove all paragraphs starting strings in a list (non-case sensitive): `["keyword", "disclosure"]`

My code:

```py
re.sub("(?i)\n(keyword|disclosure).*(\n|$)", "\n", txt)
```

This works fine if there is at least one paragraph between the bad paragraphs, but it does not work if there is more than one bad paragraph in a row.
For example:

```markdown
Text text text
Keywords: text text, text. Texts
Disclosures of stuff text more texts
Stuff text text
```

Results in the subsequent bad paragraphs getting missed:

```markdown
Text text text
Disclosures of stuff text more texts
Stuff text text
```

Instead of what I would like to see:

```
Text text text
Stuff text text
```

How can I ensure all repeated matches are also replaced? Preferably I'd also like repeated matches treated as the same match so I don't get extra newlines, but if it's much cleaner and easier to just replace repeated newlines with a newline after, that's ok.

Comment: It won't find overlapping matches, and the `\n` at the end of the first match is also the `\n` at the beginning of the next match. Use lookarounds so the newlines aren't included in the matches. Or use `^` and `$` along with the `re.MULTILINE` flag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `'\n'` at the start and end of the match overlap with each other for consecutive matches. Instead, use `^` to match the start, which will also cover the case where the string starts with a paragraph you want to remove. It requires flag [`MULTILINE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE) to work. The replacement then becomes the null string.

```
import re

txt = '''\
Text text text
Keywords: text text, text. Texts
Disclosures of stuff text more texts
Stuff text text'''

result = re.sub("(?im)^(keyword|disclosure).*(\n|$)", "", txt)
print(result)
```

```
Text text text
Stuff text text
```

Comment: Multiline!! Thank you, this is what I needed ><

Answer (score 2):

```py
import re

txt = """
Text text text
Keywords: text text, text. Texts
Disclosures of stuff text more texts
Stuff text text
"""

keywords = ["keyword", "disclosure"]

pattern = "(?i)^(" + "|".join(keywords) + ").*?(\n|$)"
result = re.sub(pattern, "", txt, flags=re.MULTILINE)

print(result)
```

Output

```
Text text text
Stuff text text
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `re.MULTILINE` (i.e. `(?m)`) and `^`/`$` anchors:

```
import re


txt = """
Text text text
Keywords: text text, text. Texts
Disclosures of stuff text more texts
Stuff text text
"""

print(re.sub("(?mi)^(keyword|disclosure).*$", "", txt))
```

prints out

```
Text text text


Stuff text text
```

and you can then clean out multiple newlines (since this will have replaced the entire line with an empty string) if you need to.

Comment: Thanks! This got me close but the solution @wjandrea posted using `(\n|$)` instead of `$` also conveniently solved the issue of extra newlines :3